# How do I increase the permgem space in springsource tc server?

Tags: tomcat, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

I get the Java out of memory error when deploying using springsourcetool (STS). Googling and searching here on SO, the suggestions have been to increase the permgem space. However, most of the instructions are for tomcat.

I use STS and therefore, the server is actually tc server. How do I increase the permgem space for tc server? I think it is separate from tomcat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tc server is based on tomcat ( http://www.springsource.com/developer/tcserver ), so your instructions should apply to tc server as well. Alternatively you can just use a tomcat in the sts.